# What are correct python path splitting methods for use with Azure Blob

Tags: python, azure, path, blob

When using Azure Bobs the path separator is a slash (`/`). As Blobs are flat there are no actual directories. However, often there are prefixes that should be treated as directories.

What are the right methods to deal with such paths? `os.path` is os dependent and will assume backslashes e.g. on Windows machines.

Simply using `str.split('/')` and similar does not feel right, as I would like to have the features from `os.path` to combine paths and I don't want to care about trailing and leading slashes and so on.

Comment: what's your purpose? split the blob name which has prefix?

Comment: Yes, basically I have Blob names like `/some/long/path/and/a/file.txt`. But `os.path` would use backslash on Windows systems, I guess.

Comment: added an answer. If it's helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks. And if I misunderstood it, please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

I normally do use `str.split('/')`. Don't know if its the "right" method but it works fine for me. Later on I can use `os.path.join()` to combine the resulting strings again (when needed).

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I misunderstand you.

For example, if the blob name is `/some/long/path/and/a/file.txt`. In windows and linux,  it's ok to use `os.path.split(blob)` for splitting virtual directories and file name.

The result is as below for both windows and linux:

```
('/some/long/path/and/a', 'file.txt')
```

In windows, when using `os.path.join()` method, it will use backslash. At this time, you can just use `replace` method like below:

```
os.path.join('/some/long/path/and/a','file.txt').replace('\\','/')
```

Then the result is: `/some/long/path/and/a/file.txt`